# Is it possible to remove properties from a dynamic class?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, class, actionscript, dynamic

I have a dynamic ActionScript Class that is used to send parameters to a WebService. Some of these parameters are always present, so they are public properties of the Class:

```
package
{
    [Bindable]
    public dynamic class WebServiceCriteria
    {
        public var property1:int;

        public var property2:String;

        public var property3:String;

        public var property4:String;
    }
}
```

But, I am also adding properties at runtime that can change over time:

```
criteria.runTimeProperty = "1";
```

I'm not very familiar with using dynamic classes, so I was wondering if it is possible to "remove" the new property. Let's say the next time I call the WebService I don't want that property sent - not even as a null. How can I remove it from the Class instance without creating a new instance each time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe all you'd need to do is this:

```
delete criteria.runTimeProperty;
```

or

```
delete criteria["runTimeProperty"];
```

Either should do the same thing.

See the [delete](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/operators.html#delete) documentation for specifics.

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed that one!